# To display another fragment from a fragmentwrapper

Tags: android-nested-fragment

I have a custom `FragmentWrapper` class from which I want to return a new instance every time.

But inside it, I wan't to display another `Singleton Fragment` from each instance.

i.e.
There should be a `single fragment` of `SingletonFragment`.
And, all the instances of `FragmentWrapper` should display that `Singleton fragment.`

I tried using `nested fragment` through `fragmentchildmanager` but it is not working.

Below is the code:

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxlayout, container, false);

    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.xxxcontainer, singletonfragment)

            .commit();

    return root;

}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

after commit add following line

```
getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

like this:

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxlayout, container, false);

    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

            .replace(R.id.xxxcontainer, singletonfragment)

            .commit();
    getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    return root;

}
```